# Get wildcard value from regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that follows a pattern like

```
//[x][y]\n1*2%3
```

Where the values of x and y are variable.

Is there a way for me to extract these values into javascript variables?

Comment: Of course. Personally, I'd recommend spending an hour or two with some basic regex tutorials. They're a really important thing to know, and you'll be better served by figuring them out on your own than being fed an answer.

Comment: ok, so I'm getting close with this by using a wildcard

.match(/\[.\]/g)   // returns ['[x]', '[y]']

but if I want to have multiple chars:
.match(/\[.+\]/g)  // returns [ '[x][y]' ]

obviously I want the 2nd result to be the same as the 1st

Comment: @Cathal, please provide some example text and we'll get this squared away.

Comment: You will also need grouping and capturing, as seen here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html